# Convert List<int> to byte[]

Tags: serialization, .net-2.0, arrays

In .NET 2.0 is there an API that lets me quickly convert a list of integers to a byte array (`List<int>` to `byte[]`)? The resulting byte array should be the bitwise binary representation of the sequence of integer values, so serailizing the the List  instance using default .NET type serialization wouldn't work.

Comment: Serialization in what context? Automatically as part of binary serialization / XML serialization / whatever else, or manually?

Comment: Also, did you consider endianness?

Comment: @Ondrej endianess doesn't matter in my case. All that matters is that the byte array contain (only) all the bits in of the integers in the same order.

Comment: In that case I think @thecoop provided a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
int[] intArray = intList.ToArray();
byte[] byteArray = new byte[intArray.Length*4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(intArray, 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

[`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) uses raw memory addresses, not array indexes, to copy array data. It only works on arrays of primitives.